# Abuse flag declined for a user repeatedly attacking another user

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, code-of-conduct

In this thread, the OP of the question received a clearly well-meaning answer, which he obviously felt was not right:

[Spring Boot Callback after client receives resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036981/spring-boot-callback-after-client-receives-resource/53037486#53037486)

He commented "Please don't answer if you don't know what you're talking about".

I flagged that as 'harassment, bigotry, or abuse', because

> It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.
>   This comment attacks a person or group.

Telling someone (who has gone out of his way to help you) that he doesn't know what he's talking about seems like a pretty clear-cut case of 'attacking a person' in my eyes, and I'd also say should result in some kind of repurcussions (at least a warning) even for a single offence.

The comment thread continues with the user who gave the answer remaining perfectly calm and even continuing to help the OP, who repeats his assertion that the answerer doesn't know what he's talking about, and gets increasingly unfriendly. I flagged several of his other comments as either 'harassment, bigotry, or abuse' or 'unfriendly or unkind'.

My first 'harassment, bigotry, or abuse' was declined, although the comment seems to have been deleted, but the others remain at 'pending'.

Am I being over-sensitive to see that comment as abusive? I'm also interested in why the other comments have not been addressed? Every other time I've flagged multiple comments under a single post, they've all been addressed together.

Comment: Didn't the "unkind" flag seem enough for this? Or even the NLN flag?

Comment: I considered it, but based on the definition quoted above, "attacks a person" seems more appropriate to me. I feel like actively calling someone incompetent is more than just 'unkind'.

Comment: I think _unfriendly or unkind_ might've been more appropriate here. I tend to reserve _Harassment, bigotry, or abuse_ for more plain abuse, e.g. direct insults unrelated to code shared or actions taken

Comment: As it said *Please* in the comment at least we are harassed in a kindly manner ...

Comment: It's fairly clear that I'm the outlier here, so will attempt to re-calibrate my interpretation of what's offensive, thanks all. I wonder if my British background is part of it - when all insults are veiled, perhaps it's too easy to see insulting intent in statements that others consider perfectly innocuous. :)

Comment: Isn't it kinda silly that you are forced to choose between the two?  If the CMs had any confidence in the CoC being a workable document that defines proper behavior then they'd get rid of both of them and replace them with a single "Violates the CoC".  I don't buy much stock in mods having to handle them with different priorities.

Answer (score 11):

If the comment quote is accurate, I believe your use of that flag was over the top, and the mod decision of declining the flag but deleting the comment was the right call.

The comment was, allegedly:

> Please don't answer if you don't know what you're talking about

The flag definition that you cite:

> It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse. This comment attacks a person or group.

That comment didn't contain abuse, bigotry or harrassment. You can make a very thin case of making an "attack" because it implies the asker "doesn't know what are they talking about".

The insinuation is certainly *unkind*, and most assuredly *not needed*, but it doesn't raise to the level of a rude flag.

To further drive the point, I do believe that the comment you flagged, compared to this hypothetical one, are very different:

> Clearly you have no clue what you are talking about. Get a clue before posting uninformed drivel.

This second hypothetical comment, is clearly rude and abusive.

The one you flagged, is quite milder; doesn't even make a direct attack but an insinuation. Still unfriendly and unkind. Still flaggable and we are better by it being deleted.

Accumulating those flags may have direct consequences for the users involved, so we should reserve their use when they are actually apropriate.

We have 4 different levels of flags to ask for a comment removal. There is a reason we have both "unkind" and "rude" flags available. Let's use the more accurate when we do so, if for not other reason to make the lives of our beloved moderators easier.

Comment: I'd accept that it's a borderline case, I certainly hovered my mouse over both 'unkind' and 'abuse' before eventually deciding on abuse, because of the description that it 'attacks a person'. Clearly you disagree that it's attacking a person (and of course that's always going to be somewhat subjective), but a comment that says nothing other than to call someone incompetent is (to me) very much an attack. If it had included some explanation as to why he felt that it didn't answer the question, I'd agree with 'unkind', but this comment is nothing but a personal attack. IMHO, obvs.

Comment: Regarding the abuse flag having direct consequences - absolutely - and that was part of my reasoning. This person sustained an attack (IMHO) against someone who was actively trying to help him. I don't think that's someone I'd want on SO, personally.

Comment: I might add that this was the very first comment that's ever provoked me to raise an abuse flag, so it's not like I use them lightly.

Comment: yivi is correct, I'm declining borderline usage of rude/abusive comment flags. If in doubt, use unfriendly/unkind flag instead, or if multiple comments are needed to be looked at, I recommend just a single custom flag.

Comment: To clarify, this wasn't "happening in the context of a longer discussion" it was the first comment, which ultimately started the longer discussion. I really can't see any difference in _intent_ between the actual comment and your hypothetical one.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Regarding the first point, I wasn't aware of that. Regarding the second point, can't help you there. I can see a huge difference between those two comments.

Comment: @SamuelLiew - seriously? So no negative consequences for a user telling another user that they don't know what they're talking about, without providing any explanation as to why? I really don't see how that fits with "No name-calling or personal attacks. / Focus on the content, not the person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (e.g. “lazy”)."

Comment: Those looked more like unkind comments than abusive. Yes, it's subjective. No, I did not say there won't be consequences for the user.

Comment: @Davey, can you give me a couple examples of comments you'd flag as "unkind" but not as "rude", to help me understand how you perceive the difference?

Comment: @SamuelLiew - I always assumed that custom flags required more effort from mods, so have avoided using them in cases like this, although good to know that assumption was wrong - I'll do that next time.

Comment: @yivi - from this comment, I think I'd have gone for 'unkind' if it had been something like "You clearly don't know what you're talking about - using a Thread.sleep in this way is bad because...". I guess the wording of the CoC says it well - "focus on the content, no the person". By not referencing the content, this comment said 'personal attack' to me, because the only thing it referred to is the knowledge of the person.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave maybe I should've stopped the conversation after my "Please don't answer if you don't know what you're talking about" comment. but when you ask 1+1=? and someone answers 3 and they persist on it, I can only replicate by calling them incompetent, call that rude, I call it saying the truth. Answers of the kind only waste the time of the OP and mislead people who might have the same question in the future. The attitude I gave had one goal: stopping the person from misleading people in the future. It's a shame to learn that calling things by their name incur punishment in SOF : /

Comment: @ALTN No need to take upon yourself the responsability to educate every user you find in the site needing education. People are going to be misled no matter what. If you thought the answer was wrong, with voting the answer you were doing enough. Commenting on the content? Bonus points. But if you can't say anything useful without getting personal, just refrain of commenting altogether. Those comments are **not** useful for anyone.

Comment: @yivi I was not purely harassing the answerer, I gave them arguments as for why their answer were wrong. I agree I might've gone a bit overboard, but I did explain the problem in their answer.

Comment: ... and I'm deleting the question, it's only got down-rates, clearly a worthless question... peace out :)
Edit: I'm not even allowed to delete a worthless question

Comment: @ALTN You've got positively scored answers. I don't think you can delete it. And it would be in very poor form if you could anyway.

Comment: I wonder if my "evil" comments weren't there, and people focus on the content instead of empathizing, how many upvotes the answer would get.

Comment: @ALTN Another great reason not to leave those, maybe.

Comment: @ALTN, given that it had no votes (up or down) before I posted this, that none of the votes are mine, and that presumably they are not the other commenter's either (as, again there were no votes when I created this post), AND given that the overwhelming sentiment here seems to be that my reaction was wrong, it seems unlikely that people came here and decided to downvote _you_, and more likely that they came here, looked at your question, and decided that the content was worth downvoting. I tend to disagree (hence I didn't downvote), but I don't think you can put it down to people empathizing.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I hope some spring expert sees this and gives their opinion, I tested the answerer solution... it doesn't work.